# C#: Resize String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, resize

I'm new to programming and I have decided to give myself a challenge by creating a random word generator based on user input.
I'm trying to put the user's words inside of an array and then display a random word from the the array. When I run the program I am able to enter up to four words and then I receive an error: "Array index is out of range."

Is there a limit to how many times I can resize an array?

```
using System;

namespace RandomWordGenerator
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random ();
        string[] words = new string[1];
        Console.WriteLine ("Enter words for the random word generator. ");

        int a = 0;
        while(!(Console.ReadLine().Equals("END"))){
            words[a] = Console.ReadLine();
            a++;
            Array.Resize(ref words, a);
        }

        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine (words[r.Next (a)]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you resizing the array on each iteration of your `while` loop? You could simply use a `List<T>`.

Comment: I don't even see how you get to 4 elements. The code looks like it would crash on the second word entered, because the first call to `Array.Resize()` just sets the length to 1, which is what it already was.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Look at the code flow. On the first iteration he has 2 `Console.Readline`s (One at the while loop statement, the other inside the while body). On the second iteration, he's reading again from the `Console.ReadLine` in the while loop statement, and then crashes inside the while block where he tries to assign `words[a] = Console.ReadLine()` (On the 4th readline call).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: hmmm...well, I made the (possibly silly?) assumption that each entered word was intentionally on every other entered line. I.e. that four words entered would take four loop iterations. But you're right...if the extra `ReadLine()` is _also_ a bug, that would explain his "enter up to four words" comment. That does seem more plausible.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think he means "On the 4th `ReadLine`" instead of actually the 4th word. That wouldn't make sense, the code will crash on the first iteration as you said.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: agreed. I think it's also possible he thinks he's entering four words, and just doesn't yet realize he's ignoring half of them (because of course the code crashes before that other bug would be revealed). :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, I mean 4th ReadLine. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in c# are **immutable**, which is to say they cannot be changed after creating them.

What you want is a `List<string>`, which can be resized at will.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random ();
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine ("Enter words for the random word generator. ");

        int a = 0;
        while(!(Console.ReadLine().Equals("END"))){
            words.Add(Console.ReadLine());
       }

        Console.WriteLine ();
        Console.WriteLine (words[r.Next(words.Count)]);
    }
}
```

`Array.Resize` is actually not named very well, since it does something different than actual resizing. From the MSDN documents:

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.

The `List<>` class is designed for a dynamically sized collection, and in many cases is a better choice than a raw array.

Comment: at will ? you dont have control of that. ( unless initially constructed with size)

Comment: `Array.Resize` allocates a new array each time and assigns it to `words`. He isn't resizing the current array.

Comment: The array length is immutable. But arrays themselves are not immutable. It's an important distinction and worth expressing correctly.

Comment: Excellent! Everything works now and I have learned something new. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing an `IndexOutOfRangeException` is because you're trying to access an array with an index outside of its current range:

```
int a = 0;
while(!(Console.ReadLine().Equals("END")))
{
    words[a] = Console.ReadLine();
    a++;
    Array.Resize(ref words, a);
}
```

After the first iteration, you're trying to access `words[a]` where `a = 1`, but the array index is **zero based**, hence you're trying to access `words[1]` where the array only has 1 element located at the `words[0]` index, because you allocated a new array with `Array.Resize`, passing `a (1)` as its size. That is why you're seeing the exception.

A problem to your solution is as @rossipedia stated. Simply use a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions about using `List` are all good and valid, but direct answer to your specific question is following -

```
Array.Resize(ref words, a);
```

should be changed to -

```
Array.Resize(ref words, a + 1);
```

Reason - You start with `a=0;`, set `words[0]` to value read, set `a=1`, and then ask runtime to resize your array **from size 1 to 1**.. rest follows.